# Ternary Operator Question

Tags: php, variables, get, ternary-operator

Can someone give me an example of how to use the PHP ternary operator which will check for a variable using $_GET (which can be defined in the URL), if it's not in the URL then check if the var was set in another PHP file. If it wasn't set in the URL or another PHP file, then I want it to equal "default".

Comment: Well, how would you do this *without* the ternary? Once that is done, changing the form -- if practical -- becomes a trivial exercise. (That is, show *existing code* to do what is desired.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "check if the var was set in another PHP file"? If this other PHP file is included and the variable is not part of a class etc, it's just the same as if it would have been defined in this file and the answers below should help. But if you mean anything else with "another PHP file" you should add some details.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation, but it's a good deal to explain. Basically, I'd like to show various states using different URLs for each state, then I also need to show these various states in many pages throughout the site, which I'd just like to set in the top of each file before the include rather than having to worry about including a query string in the link for these pages. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$myVar = isset($_GET["someVar"]) ? $_GET["someVar"] : (isset($someVar) ? $someVar : "default");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$value = isset($_GET['somevar']) ? $_GET['var'] : $default_value;
```

On the most recent PHP versions, there's a shortcut version of this:

<strike>$value = isset($_GET['somevar']) ?: $default_value;</strike> (not the same as the first version)

You can use `$GLOBALS['nameofvar']` to see if a particular PHP variable has been defined as well, though this'll be problematic if you're doing the check inside a function.

Comment: Will that shortcut work as expected with `isset`? My understanding is that it will return the result of the expression (which would be `true` in the case of `isset(...)`), and so you'd need to use something like `$_GET['somevar'] ?: $default_value;`

Comment: If there is no `somevar` in the script's query, then `$_GET['somevar']` will not exist and isset() will return false. However, nothing says that some other part of your script can't fiddle with $_GET before it reaches this ternary operator.

Comment: Note: because isset returns a boolean the `$value` in the shortcut version will be boolean true if `$_GET['somevar']` is set

Comment: Right, but `isset($_GET['somevar'])` does not evaluate to the same thing as `$_GET['somevar']`... which means that using the ternary shortcut `isset($_GET['somevar']) ?: $default_value;` will return `1` if $_GET['somevar'] is set, instead of the value of $_GET['somevar']. _EDIT:_ what @Glass Robot said. Cheers.

Comment: Ahh, I gotcha now. Was misreading. You're right. The second version wouldn't work the same as the first. It's been a long day...

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET["MyVar"]))
{
    $newVar = $_GET["MyVar"];
}
else if(isset($myVar))
{
    $newVar = $myVar;
}
else
{
    $newVar = "default";
}
```

or

```
$newVar = isset($_GET["MyVar"]) ? $_GET["MyVar"] : (isset($myVar) ? $myVar : "default");
```